# What does the author mean by saying "dartboards and blindfolds are sometimes invoked"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this in Word by Word by Kory Stamper:

> Folks assume that I spend my day in a locked, smoky conference room, chomping on cigars and guzzling scotch, where other lexicographers and I bark out the latest, greatest additions to the language like caricature admen. Dartboards and blindfolds are sometimes invoked; extensive bribery setups are hinted at-how else did "Xerox" and "Kleenex" get into the dictionary.

I want to ask what type of image and idea does author want to convey with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dartboards and blindfolds" refers to the idea of throwing darts at a map, or a chart, while blindfolded. One then uses where they land to make a decision. In other words, a random guess.

Here is one [example usage](https://www.forbes.com/sites/rickferri/2012/12/20/any-monkey-can-beat-the-market) (from Forbes magazine)

> **Any Monkey Can Beat The Market**
>
> Give a monkey enough darts and they’ll beat the market. So says a draft article by Research Affiliates highlighting the simulated results of 100 monkeys throwing darts at the stock pages in a newspaper. The average monkey outperformed the index by an average of 1.7 percent per year since 1964. That’s a lot of bananas!

Here is [another example](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DecisionDarts) (from TVTropes)

> **Decision Darts**
>
> When you must make a difficult choice, what better way to resolve things than by writing a list of the options, then tacking it to the wall and throwing darts at it (perhaps while blindfolded)? Sometimes this can indicate that the character doesn't care much about the outcome of the choice, which might be something quite trivial.

So the paragraph is invoking an image of what some people might suppose it was like in the lexicographer's room where Kory Stamper worked.

She continues with "extensive bribery setups" suggesting how some people think that proprietary names have found their way into the dictionary.

Comment: do you mean that those are proprietary names? And what are "caricature admen"?

Comment: Yes, spelling mistake sorry.

Comment: A "caricature" is a cartoon representation, which exaggerates features. "Admen" are advertising agents.

Comment: What, if any, similarity is there between them and lexicographers?

Comment: None. It is an imagery which Kory Stamper is projecting onto other people, what she supposes *they* imagine it was like to be a lexicographer. In other words, the lexicographers' room and their actions were nothing like what she is describing.